# Python 3: Is this a float or a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, floating-point

I have a class which has the attribute 'latest_level' and this should be a floating point number. I then have a method which includes latest_level in an equation to return another floating point number. In this method, if I use the line:

```
def relative_water_level(self):
    level = float(self.latest_level)
```

I get the output:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Which I assume means self.latest_level is a list. If I change this line to:
    def relative_water_level(self):

```
    level = float(self.latest_level[0])
```

I get the output:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Which I assume means self.latest_level is a float. Anybody have any idea why this is happening and how I can get it to treat self.latest_level as a float?

Edit: I don't try and subscript later. The rest of the method is:

```
level = float(self.latest_level[0])
        low = float(self.typical_range[0])
        high = float(self.typical_range[1])
        return ((level - low)/high)
```

And the Error specifies that the Error is in the line mentioned above

```
File "C:\Users\rache\Documents\Flood Warning\partia-flood-warning
system\floodsystem\station.py", line 58, in relative_water_level
level = float(self.latest_level[0])

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Hi, Rachel and welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be best to include code demonstrating this behavior such that we can verify it. Without it, we can't really give useful answers (and must resort to guessing). It could be that after casting to float you subscript it, we can't really know, though.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for your advice. I'll add some extra code to the question

Comment: Please show the full error stack trace for those two errors. If those errors are happening in the same method, it’s possible that the method is called at two different times where `latest_level` is a float once, and a list the other time.

Comment: Good point, thanks Poke. I'll have a look through and see if I can find where it could be being called twice

Answer (score 0):

subscriptable object refers to something which implements `__getitem__()` method. you might be changing latest_level's type. I have added a sample code which will produce the same error.

```
class Level:
latest_level = 20.0
def getLevels(self):
    self.latest_level = [20,30]
def relative_water_level(self):
    level = float(self.latest_level[0])
    print(level)

waterLevel = Level()
waterLevel.relative_water_level()
waterLevel.getLevels()
waterLevel.relative_water_level()
```

for debugging use type(self.latest_level) before float(self.latest_level) and change according to stack trace.

Comment: Good idea with the debugging. It says that latest_level is in fact a float. I still can't understand why it treats it as a list when I want to use it in an equation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I need to see the code obviously its changing the type somewhere. Can you show me the code someway?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Turns out some of the flood monitoring stations I'm importing data from are producing messed up data with lists of numbers all over the place, so I've just had to ignore those stations for now. Thanks for all your help and good luck to any of you who live near those rivers!